# Strange font in Windows experience Index

Tags: fonts, windows-experience-index

Just recently had a look at my WEI and the font is either damaged or wrong (it was OK last time I looked).

[image]

All other aspects of the system seem fine.  Any idea how to fix this or what font is used to generate the score box?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer (because it doesn't really answer why) but it seems to have fixed the error.  I'm posting this just in case someone else ever comes across the same error.

Thinking about it I thought Microsoft = USA and being Aussie all my settings are set to Australian so I changed my 'current location' and 'current system locale' to 'English (United States)' in the Control Panel Region and Language settings and bingo it looks the way it should.   The strange this is, just to confirm, I changed the settings back to Australian and it still looks OK!!.  I can only assume that whatever was wrong was reset in the process.